# Programmatically disable rails validation ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am doing a bulk insert where I keep track of the unique columns myself to avoid the m log n insertion cost.  Is there a way to disable a validation in code for the life if the method?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

one way to do that

```
new_car=Car.new(...)

new_car.save(validate: false)
```

other way to use that

```
Model.skip_callback(:create)
```

to remove that and apply it back

```
Model.set_callback(:create)
```

Comment: Doesn't make any difference on Rails 5.1. Still `::create!` raises a validaiton error. Actually my issue is that if I put `config load_defaults 5.1` in `application.rb`, then db seeding fails because of validation errors. And without this call, there are no validation errors.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for `update_column`: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_column

or Rails 4 `update_columns`: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_columns

And here is some info from the guides about skipping validations: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#skipping-validations

Or you can use `update_all` to change the same column on many records at once: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all , Rails 4 docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all

Or you could just execute the raw SQL using `execute` (Rails 4 docs): http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.2/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-execute , here is a StackOverflow question about doing this: [Rails raw SQL example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824453/rails-raw-sql-example) and here is another one: [Rails 3, custom raw SQL insert statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12716797/rails-3-custom-raw-sql-insert-statement)

Comment: If you know what you are about, you might just want to go with raw SQL, that'll enable you to craft your SQL to be exactly what you want.

Comment: How do you skip a particular validation?